# Adobe Air for IPhone

Tags: iphone, adobe, air

We have developed Air application and next step it is porting this application to the IPhone/IPad.
So, I have downloaded and start to use [packagerforiphone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/)

After packaging and try to run application on IPhone I can see only white screen.
Could you help me and tell How to resolve this problem, and Does anybody had the same problem in? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're [not the only one](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/packager-for-iphone-refresher.html) with this problem. Have you tried following [this blog post's suggestions](http://blog.alastairdawson.com/2010/10/27/getting-a-blank-screen-when-using-adobes-flash-packager-for-iphone/)?

Comment: I have used article in blog that you have written above.